# How to remove captcha in via terminal?

Tags: magento2, forms, cli, captcha, magento2.2.0

I want to remove the captcha and its input field from the forgot password form and admin.

[image: Magento 2 captcha]

Please help me to remove that.

Answer (score 17):

**If you prefer to run commands instead of going to admin panel:**

Disable **admin** login captcha

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/captcha/enable 0
```

Disable **frontend** captcha ( If form specific captcha is required then please check the Prince Patel's answer )

```
php bin/magento config:set customer/captcha/enable 0
```

Answer (score 7):

> Google reCaptcha is now default added into Magento version 2.4.x

**To enable/disable reCaptcha for frontend forms:**

```
Admin->Configuration->Security->Google reCAPTCHA Storefront
```

**To enable/disable reCaptcha for admin forms:**

```
Admin->Configuration->Security->Google reCAPTCHA Admin Panel
```

---

> For normal captcha in the older version of Magento

**To enable/disable captcha for frontend forms:**

```
Admin->Configuration->Stores->Customers->Customer Configuration->CAPCTHA->Forms
```

**To enable/disable captcha for admin forms:**

```
Admin->Configuration->Stores->Advanced->Admin->CAPCTHA->Forms
```

Comment: "via terminal" 

Answer (score 3):

There are two commands to disable recaptcha in Magento 2.4.4:

1. Disable reCAPTCHA for admin user forgot password form:

   ```
   bin/magento security:recaptcha:disable-for-user-forgot-password
   ```
2. Disable reCAPTCHA for admin user login form:

   ```
   bin/magento security:recaptcha:disable-for-user-login
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can run these commands to disable it:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar"
n98 config:store:set msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled 0
n98 config:store:set msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/backend/enabled 0
n98 config:store:set admin/captcha/enable 0
n98 config:store:set customer/captcha/enable 0
n98 config:store:set recaptcha/general/enabled 0
n98 s:upgrade
n98 c:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Forget Password for the admin section, it is found under:

Stores => Settings => Configuration => Advanced => Admin

And Scroll down to CAPTCHA

Comment: "via terminal" 

Answer (score 0):

To disable recaptcha totally on my dev computer I ended up with these entries in my env.php file.

The type_for's setting to null was what resolved the recaptcha issue for me, as *Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi* and similar only check if keys and type are set instead of checking an enabled config setting.

```php
<?php
return [
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            "admin" => [
                'captcha' => [
                    'enable' => 0
                ]
            ],
            "customer" => [
                'captcha' => [
                    'enable' => 0
                ]
            ],
            "recaptcha" => [
                'general' => [
                    'enabled' => 0
                ]
            ],
            "msp_securitysuite_recaptcha" => [
                'frontend' => [
                    'enabled' => 0
                ],
                'backend' => [
                    'enabled' => 0
                ]
            ],
            "aminvisiblecaptcha" => [
                'frontend' => [
                    'enabled' => 0,
                    'default_forms' => null
                ],
                'backend' => [
                    'enabled' => 0
                ],
                'advanced' => [
                    'enabled_captcha_for_guests_only' => 0
                ]
            ],
            'recaptcha_frontend' => [
                'type_for' => [
                    'customer_login' => null,
                    'customer_forgot_password' => null,
                    'customer_create' => null,
                    'customer_edit' => null,
                    'contact' => null,
                    'product_review' => null,
                    'newsletter' => null,
                    'sendfriend' => null
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2.4.6
Just run following command
bin/magento security:recaptcha:disable-for-user-login

Comment: What about the "Forgot password" form? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/354936/

Answer (score 0):

If Google captcha, use the following:

```
bin/magento config:set recaptcha_backend/type_for/user_login ""
```